# Getting error while installing NetExtender in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, vpn, openjdk, vmware-workstation

Unable to install netextender in Ubuntu while executing `./install` in termnal. The error coming is

```
./install: line 302: /usr/sbin/netExtender: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `file /usr/sbin/netExtender`. Do not use Add comment.